# Resolving Macro Variables in a Server Session

Tags: macros, server, sas, remote-access, sas-macro

I have this code connecting to my server session in BASE SAS, but I cannot use this %LET command within the server session, is this because my macro is created locally and can only resolve locally? Do I need to use another %LET Statement in the RSUBMIT command, or should I use a command like %SYSLPUT?

EDIT: This code is still not resolving.

```
%LET yymm = 1606 ;
%PUT &yymm;
                    /* Identify the Month that you want the files to be named */

%LET mon = June ; 
%PUT &mon;
                    /* Specifying the Recipients of the CRA Error files */

%LET recip = MYEMAILs



%MACRO CFPB(date , mon);

%LET remhost=MYSERVER MYPORT;
signon remhost user=&sysuserid. password= _prompt_;
rsubmit;

    %syslput date=&date. ;
    %syslput mon=&mon. ;

LIBNAME &mon "N4.BANKCRRG.CNSRLOAN.MTRO&date." disp=shr;

    data &mon;
        set &mon..file (keep= base_cis_id acct_num acct_type);
    run;

    Proc DOWNLOAD data = &mon.;
    run;

endrsubmit;
signoff;

** INSERT SAS LOCAL STATEMENTS ***

%MEND;

%CFPB(&YYMM.,&MON.);
```

My Macro variables are STILL not resolving in the Remote Session. I, for the life of me, cannot see the error. I created my macro variables in the %LET statements, then used %SYSLPUT to create new macro variables inside my macro, inside my server session,  and then when I called my macro I used the macros I created in the %LET statements to resolve to the ones I called, and furthermore resolve with %SYSLPUT.

Comment: Your LET should be in your RSubmit so it's declared on the server otherwise it's only on your local session. You can also use syslput. Use whichever your comfortable with.

Comment: So I can use %SYSLPUT outside of the RSUBMIT statement? I want to be able to use that macro variable YYMM = 1606 in my entire code and not have to do it within the RSUBMIT as well as outside.

Comment: If you want synchronization of macrovariables between your remote session and local session check `CSYSRPUTSYNC` option of `RSUBMIT`.

Comment: Your %SYSLPUT statements are inside the RSUBMIT block. They need to be before the RSUBMIT statement.

Comment: That worked Tom, thanks!! I knew it was something small, but I couldn't figure it out.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `%syslput` outside of the `rsubmit` block provided that you've already signed onto remote the server, or `autosignon` is set to yes. For example:

```
%let remhost=MYSERVER MYPORT;

signon remhost user=_prompt_ password=_prompt_;

%syslput yymm = 1066 / remote=rsession1;

rsubmit remote=rsession1;

    LIBNAME june "LIBNAME" disp=shr;

    data june;
        set june.file (keep=base_cis_id acct_num acct_type);
    run;

    Proc DOWNLOAD data = june;
    run;

endrsubmit;
signoff;**
```

Equivalently, you can use a `%let` statement within the `rsubmit` block. Either will generate a global macro variable on the remote server. I personally prefer `%syslput` and `%sysrput` to help visually keep track of which macro variables are in my session or the remote session. `rsubmit` and macro variables can quickly turn into Macroception.